# AppSync BatchPutItem error: "The number of conditions on the keys is invalid"

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, aws-appsync

I am getting the error: "The number of conditions on the keys is invalid" when attempting to batch put items.

**Template**

```
{
  version: '2018-05-29',
  operation: 'BatchPutItem',
  tables: {
    ItemTable: [
      {
        accountId: { S: 'f586fb14-6d80-4635-9d2e-d33a1bd49f96' },
        itemId: { S: '16e89b71-271c-4ccd-81ad-55f496b15e6f' }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Table Schema

```
{
  "AttributeDefinitions": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "itemId",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "accountId",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    }
  ],
  "TableName": "ItemTable",
  "KeySchema": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "accountId",
      "KeyType": "HASH"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "itemId",
      "KeyType": "RANGE"
    }
  ],
  "TableStatus": "ACTIVE"  
}
```

If I only try to add one of the key I get the expected error of missing a key. If I setup table to use a single partition key then it works. I can also batchwrite using code just not with AppSync.

I am testing this locally w serverless appsync/dynamodb local. All other single item queries and mutation work fine. I am not sure I understand what it's asking - what is a "condition" in this case?

I have tried on every table with same result. I see no indications in docs that batch cannot be done on composite keys but that is what it appears to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gah.. it was a bug in serverless appsync offline plugin. It was emulating the return by fetching the items that it was writing and had a bug whereas it did not deal with composite keys.

Comment: What'd you do to work around it? I'm getting this error message and somewhat stumped.

Comment: Are you using the deprecated AppSync offline plugin specifically? Or just getting the message in some other context?

Comment: No, not that plugin, just getting the error in response to a straightforward mutation, which writes the data, but returns a similar. It might have to do with a bug in the local mock environment, though.

Comment: Ah - that error can have diff sources- in my case this was specifically a bug in the plugin which I fixed